# Create multiple values for a key in json

Tags: python, json

I want to create a json file that has a format similar to this:

```
{
    “cars”: {
        “model”: “Volkswagon X5”,
        “options”: [{
            “color”: “red”,
            “features”: [“automatic”, “4-wheel-drive”]
        }, {
            “color”: “blue”,
            “features”: [“automatic”, “2-wheel-drive”]
        }]
    }
}
```

I would like to use the standard `json` library preferably, but I am open to using other libraries. I am using Python 2.7.9.

I get a value (color & features) for the key `'options'` in a loop and I would like to update the dict every time I go through the loop to include another value to the dict for key `'options'`.

I saw a lot of questions like this one but most suggest using:

`my_dict["cars"]["options"].append(...)`

which doesn't work because 'dict' object has no attribute `append`.

Also, using

`my_dict["cars"]["options"]={'color':'green', features:["X","Y"]}` or `update()`

**replaces** the value for the key `'options'` rather than appending the value.

Comment: What, precisely, is your question?

Comment: Use a [`collections.defaultdict(list)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#defaultdict-examples) instead of a regular `dict`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `append` should works, the problem then is that `my_dict["cars"]["options"]` value is not a list.

You can try this as well

```
my_dict["cars"].update({
'options': my_dict.get("cars").get("options") + [{'color':'green', features:["X","Y"]} ] 
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: Pressed enter too quickly, I am getting "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'dict' and 'list' " for this.

Comment: @Pranav As I told you, check your dict value because `my_dict["cars"]["options"]` is  a dict not a  list.

Comment: Yeah, you are right, but I need to have it as a dict.

Comment: @Pranav but in the example u posted options is not a dict is a list.